# CSS issue: vertically aligning label DIV

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having issues aligning a `<label>` that is placed inside a div.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="one-whole index-border">
   <div class="score red score--primary">
      <label>20</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.one-whole {
100%;
}
.index-border {
border-bottom: 2px solid #D2D2D2;
}
.score {
border: none;
display: inline-block;
/*  margin: 0; */
line-height: 1;
width: 120px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
color: white;
margin-bottom: 15px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.red {
background: #CC0000;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #FF3400), color-stop(100%, #CC0000));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF3400, #CC0000);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF3400, #CC0000);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#FF3400, #CC0000);
background-image: linear-gradient(#FF3400, #CC0000);
}
.score--primary {
border: 1px solid #CC0000;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I thought using `vertical-align: middle` would work, but no luck.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/aH86E/

If there is any way I could refactor my code, it would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `display: table-cell;` instead of using  <s>`display: inline-block;`</s>

```
.score {
    /* Other properties */
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH86E/1/)

---

As far as refactoring of the code goes, you can safely remove proprietary properties for `box-shadow`, `box-radius` as well as gradient codes, now it depends on you that till what level do you want to support the legacy browsers.

*Refactored CSS*

```
.one-whole {
    100%;
}

.index-border {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #D2D2D2;
}

.score {
    border: none;
    display: table-cell;
    /*  margin: 0; */
    line-height: 1;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.red {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FF3400, #CC0000);
}

.score--primary {
    border: 1px solid #CC0000;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also, I just saw that you are using `rgba()` so it is better to declare a fall back for that as well, so use,

```
.score {
    /* Other properties */
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #333; /*Equivalent to rgb(51,51,51) */
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what would the impact be of getting rid of the -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 -ms-border-radius: 6px;
 -o-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.125);

Comment: @OamPsy If you take a look here, it was required for older versions, http://caniuse.com/border-radius so you won't need that now as users won't have that old browser, even if they have it, `border-radius` won't work, but would suggest you to remove those

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `table-cell` you can always just set a `line-height` to the parent. I honestly prefer table-cell in cases where I know the container could change in height.

It will allow the content to always be centered, where with this method you would have to change `line-height` to match the height of your container.

```
.score{
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH86E/2/)